# How to choose default program to a file to be opened with same exe name?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, file-association

I am not able to select default program for a file that uses same program exe name as it used previously, but now in different folder and thus different version. When ever i select the program, it wont select anything.

How do i force Windows XP to open with the program exe path i selected, and not smart-guess which program i meant? I deleted the older program exe and now when i select new program it thinks its deleted and wont allow me to select the new one.

Comment: Have you tried assigning it to something else temporarily and then back to the original `.exe` with new path?

Comment: @Raystafarian, yes i tried that, but only when i renamed exe it was only thing that worked, but i dont want to rename exe...

Comment: Is it opening it via DDE? This can cause problems like you're describing. If you've set the path for the default file handler specifically, it should not have issues so long as it is not trying to use the usually-too-smart-for-its-own-good DDE.

Comment: What is the application which is opening the file?

Comment: @Shevek, home made app. but i believe it has nothing to do which app it is... i remember seeing this bug before in the past unfixed.

Comment: @music2myear, i dont know what is DDE.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange

Comment: @music2myear, i dont know if its using DDE, i have never heard of it. as far as i know, all default programs just sends the following command to windows: `program.exe "somefile.dat"` no DDE or whatsoever, just simple commandline params there...

Comment: Shedo's solution below is the basic and usually fool-proof method. Yes, you'll need to hack the registry, but it's not that hard, and it allows your computer to tell the difference between different EXE's with the same name.

Comment: I have had this same problem (in Windows 2008 Server) trying to change the default python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always approach it by going to the Registry Editor. If you aren't familiar with editing the registry, I suggest you back it up first before attempting anything.

You can find the extension at **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.yourextension**

For example, let's take WinRAR's **.RAR** extension. For that, I'd have to go to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rar** on the Registry Editor. As you can see on the screenshot below, the **(Default) REG_SZ** key points to **WinRAR**.

[image]

Now we will go to the registry key that actually contains the application information. That is **WinRAR** and it should be located on **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** as well. So it will be located under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WinRAR**. As you can see on the image below, under the **WinRAR** key, you can jump directly to **shell\open\command**.

[image]

As shown above, you just edit the **(Default)** key and place the path to your application inside double quotes then a space and followed by **%1** inside double quotes as well. **%1** denotes the path to your file.

I hope this somewhat lengthy explanation can serve as a template for you to be able to easily remap your file extension to your newly updated executable. Once you get the hang of this, it should be pretty easy from here-on out.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the file and depending on the file type you may already have an `Open With...` option or an `Open With` sub-menu

If not, hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while Right-Clicking on the file and you will see hidden option.

If you see `Open With...` then selecting this will allow you to browse for the executable to use.

If you see `Open With` sub-menu then the last option will be `Choose Program..` which will allow you to browse for the executable to use.

In either case there will be a check box for `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`

[image]

Comment: i tried that already: it wont let me choose it! once i select my program, it doesnt show it in the list at all, but if i rename the exe to something else, i can use it. but i dont want to rename it... i have already tried to remove associations and put it back, i tried also to open with other program and put back to the real program but nothing helps. i think only way for fix is to hard-edit the registry?

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: its a home made app.

Comment: well, when you tick that box it should do the registry for you! I'm not sure what is happening for you :(